# Creating a json output out of one item and a second as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am struggling with the following looking-so-simple-but-not-really python issue. I want to create a valid json output out of a simple item and a dictionary with the same keys.

So the wished output should look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "array": [
            {
                "item": [
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "array": [
            {
                "item": [
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Let's say I store the "one", "two", "three" items in a list that I have to iterate. I prefer the "item" keys to be the same but if one of you can help me with different keys (item_1, item_2, item_3), I might accept it also.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unclear about what the input looks like, but I think the following is what you want:

```
import json

# input data consists of records stored in lists.
items = [
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['four', 'five', 'six']
]

# create a JSON string from records
# if you want to write to file instead, see json.dump    
data = json.dumps(
    [{'id': k, 'array': [{'item': i}]} for k, i in enumerate(items, 1)],
    indent=4
)
print(data)
```

This will produce:

```
[
    {
        "array": [
            {
                "item": [
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "array": [
            {
                "item": [
                    "four",
                    "five",
                    "six"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, you made my day!